# Dynamically add a table row with a bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically add a table row. one of the td's has a bootstrap select picker field. when I add the class select picker in JavaScript the field does not render the field, when i remove the class the select field renders without the search input. i would like the select to be rendered as a bootstrap select picker rather than a plain select field

```js
function addRow() {
  $("#addRowBtn").button("loading");

  var tableLength = $("#productTable tbody tr").length;

  var tableRow;
  var arrayNumber;
  var count;

  if (tableLength > 0) {
    tableRow = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr("id");
    arrayNumber = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr("class");
    count = tableRow.substring(3);
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    arrayNumber = Number(arrayNumber) + 1;
  } else {
    // no table row
    count = 1;
    arrayNumber = 0;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "php_action/fetchProductData.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $("#addRowBtn").button("reset");

      var tr =
        '<tr id="row' +
        count +
        '" class="' +
        arrayNumber +
        '">' +
        "<td>" +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div class="search_select">' +
        '<select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" name="productName[]" id="productName' +
        count +
        '" onchange="getProductData(' +
        count +
        ')" >' +
        '<option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>';
      // console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function (index, value) {
        tr += '<option value="' + value[0] + '">' + value[1] + "</option>";
      });

      tr +=
        "</select>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;"">' +
        '<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />' +
        '</td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity' +
        count +
        '" onkeyup="getTotal(' +
        count +
        ')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" />' +
        "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />' +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        '<button class="btn btn-default removeProductRowBtn" type="button" onclick="removeProductRow(' +
        count +
        ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
      if (tableLength > 0) {
        $("#productTable tbody tr:last").after(tr);
      } else {
        $("#productTable tbody").append(tr);
        $(".search_select").selectpicker("refresh");
      }
    }, // /success
  }); // get the product data
} // /add row
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="productTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:40%;">Product</th>
                            <th style="width:20%;">Rate</th>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Quantity</th>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Total</th>
                            <th style="width:10%;"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $arrayNumber = 0;
                            for ($x = 1; $x < 4; $x++) { ?>
                        <tr id="row<?php echo $x; ?>" class="<?php echo $arrayNumber; ?>">
                            <td style="margin-left:20px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                        name="productName[]" id="productName<?php echo $x; ?>"
                                        onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)">
                                        <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                                        <?php
                                                $productSql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE active = 1 AND status = 1 AND quantity != 0";
                                                $productData = $connect->query($productSql);

                                                while ($row = $productData->fetch_array()) {
                                                    echo "<option value='" . $row['product_id'] . "' id='changeProduct" . $row['product_id'] . "'>" . $row['product_name'] . "</option>";
                                                } // /while

                                                ?>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                                <input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off"
                                    disabled="true" class="form-control" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue<?php echo $x; ?>"
                                    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity<?php echo $x; ?>"
                                        onkeyup="getTotal(<?php echo $x ?>)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
                                        min="1" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                                <input type="text" name="total[]" id="total<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off"
                                    class="form-control" disabled="true" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue<?php echo $x; ?>"
                                    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <button class="btn btn-default removeProductRowBtn" type="button"
                                    id="removeProductRowBtn" onclick="removeProductRow(<?php echo $x; ?>)"><i
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                                $arrayNumber++;
                            } // /for
                            ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to change the class of the field being rendered in javascript and render the element using the knew class name

```js
function addRow() {
  $("#addRowBtn").button("loading");

  var tableLength = $("#productTable tbody tr").length;

  var tableRow;
  var arrayNumber;
  var count;

  if (tableLength > 0) {
    tableRow = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr("id");
    arrayNumber = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr("class");
    count = tableRow.substring(3);
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    arrayNumber = Number(arrayNumber) + 1;
  } else {
    // no table row
    count = 1;
    arrayNumber = 0;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "php_action/fetchProductData.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $("#addRowBtn").button("reset");

      var tr =
        '<tr id="row' +
        count +
        '" class="' +
        arrayNumber +
        '">' +
        "<td>" +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div class="search_select">' +
        '<select class="form-control sele" data-live-search="true" name="productName[]" id="productName' +
        count +
        '" onchange="getProductData(' +
        count +
        ')" >' +
        '<option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>';
      // console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function (index, value) {
        tr += '<option value="' + value[0] + '">' + value[1] + "</option>";
      });

      tr +=
        "</select>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;"">' +
        '<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />' +
        '</td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity' +
        count +
        '" onkeyup="getTotal(' +
        count +
        ')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" />' +
        "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        '<td style="padding-left:20px;">' +
        '<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue' +
        count +
        '" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />' +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        '<button class="btn btn-default removeProductRowBtn" type="button" onclick="removeProductRow(' +
        count +
        ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
      if (tableLength > 0) {
        $("#productTable tbody tr:last").after(tr);
        $(".sele").selectpicker("render");
      } else {
        $("#productTable tbody").append(tr);
        $(".sele").selectpicker("render");
      }
    }, // /success
  }); // get the product data
} // /add row
```